# Is there a way I can choose where ASP.MVC places my form validation errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 `HTML.BeginForm` and it creates a `validation-summary-errors` class as 
below. This doesn't fit with my layout. Is there a way that I can make it put the 
validation div class in a different place?

```
<form action="/User/Account/Login" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div class="validation-summary-errors">
   <ul>
      <li>The user name or password provided is incorrect.</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Local Login</legend>
          <ol>
             <li>ation-summary-errors in a different position?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sure, it's up to you to put the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` helper call which generates this markup wherever you want. As far as controlling the exact markup that this helper spits, that would be much more difficult because this helper offers you almost no control over the generated markup.

If you need to have more control you could write a custom helper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Html.ValidationMessage("validation-errors")` and put it in any HTML tag and then can use CSS to give it a style.